# Data not entered in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

Why am I unable to enter data in to db?

```
<?php include ( './includes/header.php' ); 
$error = "";
if (@$_POST['send']) {
 $name = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
 $message = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['message']));
 if ($name == "") {
  $error = "Name cannot be left empty.";
 }
 else if ($email == "") {
        $error = "Enter valid email id";
 }
 else if ($message == "") {
  $error = "Message cannot be left empty.";
 }
 else{
 //send message
 $sendmessage = mysql_query("INSERT INTO contact VALUES('','$name','$email','$message')",$db1) or die(mysql_error());
 $error = "Message sent!!";
    }
 }
?>
<meta property="og:title" content="Contact Us" />
<meta property="og:description" content="For any help, drop us a mail" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://studyfoyer.org/images/contactus.jpg" />

<title>Contact Us</title>
</head>
<?php include('includes/navigation.php');?>


    <div class="container">   
        <div class="row">

            <form class="log-page" action="contact.php" method="POST">

                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Get in touch</h2>   
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <label for="InputUsername">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name='name' placeholder="Name" required autofocus>
                </div>
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <label for="InputEmail">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name='email' placeholder="Email address" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <label for="InputMessage">Message</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="message" placeholder="Your message" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="controls form-inline">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" name='send' type="submit">Send</button>
                </div>

                    <?php echo $error; ?>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Db connection is done through header.php
I've two websites(both on localhost) using same db, for contact info. can this affect? 
As the code seems to run fine on other one.

Comment: What error are you getting and is `$db1` properly initiated? Have you made sure the code makes it to the `else` condition? Furthermore, what have you already tried? Provide us with some more information.

Comment: there are no errors. $_POST is not working.
I've used the code previously, and it work well

Comment: What do you mean exactly by '`$_POST` is not working'? You mean the entire `if-block` doesn't execute in the first place because `$_POST` isn't set? If `$_POST` isn't set, make sure a form uses the `$_POST` method to pass data to this PHP script. PS why are you suppressing errors with `@`? Just use `isset` or `empty`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `if (isset($_POST['send']))`  instead of `if (@$_POST['send'])`. [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function will return true is $_POST['send'] is "set". Same files for db connection will not affect anything.

Your code is vulnerable to **SQL injection**. You must use prepared statements to safely sanitize user's input.

Comment: Thanks, but how come it worked previously? can you explain a bit in detail?

Comment: Can you throw some light, how to enter it more safely?

Comment: Siddharth, for sanitizing the user's input to safely store it in database you need to use prepared statements and parameterized queries. Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/) and [this](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) link. If some answer helps you don't forget to upvote it :)